# How do I use the ANT Zip Task to add selected directories recursively (with all files inside)?

Tags: ant

I want to create an ant task that zips several directories with all files inside. However, we I do:

```
    <zip destfile="${dest.backup-data-zip-filename}"
         basedir="${dest}"
         includes="data/database,data/meetings"/>
```

it only stores the directories. With

```
    <zip destfile="${dest.backup-data-zip-filename}"
         basedir="${dest}"
         includes="data/database/*,data/meetings/*"/>
```

only the direct children are added, not all files in subdirectories recursively.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution, you need to use the double star to add files recursively:

```
    <zip destfile="${dest.backup-data-zip-filename}"
         basedir="${dest}"
         includes="data/database/**,data/meetings/**"/>
```

(Actually I [read](http://grokbase.com/t/ant/user/107ckg50v7/fileset-problem) that also

```
    <zip destfile="${dest.backup-data-zip-filename}"
         basedir="${dest}"
         includes="data/database,data/meetings/"/>
```

should do the job, however this did not work for me.)